# NCalc date operations

Tags: c#, ncalc

I am using NCalc in a project. Is there a way to do date operations like

> #16/02/2013# - #15/02/2013# = 1

I can't seem to be able to produce a result.

```
Expression.Evaluate();
```

Results is null for the above expression. I can compare two dates, but is there a way to do operations on them using NCalc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) library doesn't allow to do this.

[Read](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/352767) this related topic.

But you can do it withoud of NCalc.

Assuming that `a` and `b` are of type `DateTime`, `(a - b).TotalDays` will return the number of days.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll need NCalc as I need to provide expression editing options for the end user on a GUI. Your link was really useful.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in ncalc quite easily if you are happy to create a custom function.

```
Expression e = new Expression("DayDiff(#16/02/2013#, #15/02/2013#)");
e.EvaluateFunction += delegate(string name, FunctionArgs args)
{
    if (name == "DayDiff")
    {
        var date1 = args.Parameters[0].Evaluate();
        var date2 = args.Parameters[1].Evaluate();
        var timespan = date2 - date1;
        return timespan.TotalDays; // double (you can convert to int if you wish a whole number!)
    }
}
Console.Write(e.Evaluate());
```

Comment: I think the current version requires you to return the result in `args.Result` as the EvaluateFunction is void.

[link(https://github.com/sheetsync/NCalc/wiki)

Comment: @RobVonNesselrode, sounds about right.  My answer is now four and a half years old!

Answer (score 2):

This is very late to the party but I have built an alternative option to NCalc called [Expressive](https://github.com/bijington/expressive). This is available as a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpressiveParser/) also.

It was originally built to match NCalcs functionality so migrating should require only a small amount of effort.

You can do a lot more date related functions:

```
DaysBetween(#15/02/2013#, #16/02/2013#)
```

Comment: Not just expressive, but also quite impressive. Thanks for letting me know about your project.

Comment: I like what you did there :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    DateTime Date1, Date2;
    Date1 = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-27 8:42:00");
    Date2 = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-27 8:42:26");
    TimeSpan TimeSpan1 = Date2 - Date1;
    double DayDifference = TimeSpan1.TotalDays;
```

Comment: How is it related to NCalc?

Comment: It's not.  It's merely subtracting dates in C#.